# UICollection View scroll Change Page Controller index swift3?

Tags: json, swift3, uicollectionview, swifty-json, uipagecontrol

I tried finding this question for a while but could not find this problem's answer. My problem is that i have a UICollectionView and the Scroll Direction is Horizontal with Paging Controller.
[Click Below Image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsH7N.png) 
loading UICollectionViewCell records from a JSON file and I use SwiftyJSON. So my question is how to change PageController index according my Json records? Thanks Advanced

Answer (score 0):

**1. First Enable paging for `CollectionView`**

`collectionView.pagingEnabled = true`

**2. Use below given code to calculate number of pages for `CollectionView`**

`var numberOfPages = Int(collectionView.contentSize.width / collectionView.bounds.width)`

```
let remainder = collectionView.contentSize.width % collectionView.bounds.width

 if remainder > 0.0 {
  numberOfPages += 1
 }
```

**3. Set total number pages for `UIPageControl`**

`pageControl.numberOfPages = numberOfPages`

**4. Implement `func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` and update `currentPage` of `pageControl`**

`func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {`

`let currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionView.bounds.width)`
  `pageControl.currentPage = currentPage`
 `}`

Comment: martine %' is unavailable: Use truncatingRemainder instead .. giving me error when i declare remainder ....